# Begin horizontal table lower on page

Tags: tables, margins, tabularx, geometry, landscape

I'm trying to squeeze every last bit of space out of a horizontal page with a wide table, so I'd like the table to start closer to the bottom of the page, but still equally span the full `\linewidth`. What's the most elegant way to solve this?

Here's the code so far:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, 11pt]{report}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage[left=4cm, right=2cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{ltablex} 
    \newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%%%% Configure Fancy Header %%%%%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\headsep 25pt
\headheight 20pt
\setlength{\topmargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\textheight}{670pt}

\fancypagestyle{IHA-fancy-style}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\slshape \leftmark}
  \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage\ }
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}% Line at the header visible
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}% Line at the footer visible
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{IHA-fancy-style}
\lhead{\textsf{Chapter I}}
\rhead{\textsf{Chapter Title}}

\begin{landscape}
\scriptsize
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=off, justification=justified, font=footnotesize}
\rowcolors{1}{gray!10}{white}
\def\arraystretch{1.2}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.01em}
\begin{tabularx}{1.02\linewidth}{ p{0.04\linewidth} CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC }
\hiderowcolors
\caption[Caption]{Some caption text}
\label{label}\\

\multirow{2}{*}{ORF} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{PNF}  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{CIF} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{LOPT} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{UNIT4} &  \multicolumn{2}{c}{UNIT2} & UNIT1 & UNIT3  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{LUMT} \\ \cmidrule{2-3} \cmidrule{4-6} \cmidrule{7-9} \cmidrule{10-11} \cmidrule{12-13}  \cmidrule{14-14} \cmidrule{15-15} \cmidrule{16-17}
 & 43949 & Kingscliff & 43949 & Kingscliff & TT01 & 43949 & Kingscliff & TT01 & 43949 & TT01 & Kingscliff & TT01 & TT01 & TT01 & 43949 & Kingscliff \\ 
 \hline
 \showrowcolors
\textbf{PVC1} & PAU\_03392 & PAK\_03203 & PAU\_01961 & PAK\_01787 & PLT\_02568 & PAU\_02074 & PAK\_01896 & PLT\_02424 & PAU\_02775 & PLT\_01696 & PAK\_02606 & PLT\_01736 & PLT\_01758 & PLT\_01716 & PAU\_02206 & PAK\_02014 \\ 
\textbf{PVC2} & PAU\_03391 & PAK\_03202 & PAU\_01962 & PAK\_01788 & PLT\_02567 & PAU\_02073 & PAK\_01895 & PLT\_02425 & PAU\_02776 & PLT\_01695 & PAK\_02607 & PLT\_01735 & PLT\_01757 & PLT\_01715 & PAU\_02205 & PAK\_02013 \\
\textbf{PVC3} & PAU\_03390 & PAK\_03201 & PAU\_01963 & PAK\_01789 & PLT\_02566 &  &  & PLT\_02426 & PAU\_02777 & PLT\_01694 & PAK\_02608 & PLT\_01734 & PLT\_01756 & PLT\_01714 &  & PAK\_02012 \\
\textbf{PVC4} & PAU\_03389 & PAK\_03200 & PAU\_01964 & PAK\_01790 & PLT\_02565 & PAU\_02072 & PAK\_01894 & PLT\_02427 & PAU\_02778 & PLT\_01693 & PAK\_02609 & PLT\_01733 & PLT\_01755 & PLT\_01713 & PAU\_02204 & PAK\_02011 \\
\textbf{PVC5} & PAU\_03388 & PAK\_03199 & PAU\_01965 & PAK\_01791 & PLT\_02564 & PAU\_02071 & PAK\_01893 & PLT\_02428 & PAU\_02779 & PLT\_01692 & PAK\_02610 & PLT\_01732 & PLT\_01754 & PLT\_01712 & PAU\_02203 & PAK\_02010 \\
\textbf{PVC6} & PAU\_03387 & PAK\_03198 & PAU\_01966 & PAK\_01792 & PLT\_02563 & PAU\_02070 & PAK\_01892 & PLT\_02429 & PAU\_02780 & PLT\_01691 & PAK\_02611 & PLT\_01731 & PLT\_01753 & PLT\_01711 & PAU\_02202 & PAK\_02009 \\
\textbf{PVC7} & PAU\_03386 & PAK\_03197 & PAU\_01967 & PAK\_01793 & PLT\_02562 & PAU\_02069 & PAK\_01891 & PLT\_02430 & PAU\_02781 & PLT\_01690 & PAK\_02612 & PLT\_01730 & PLT\_01752 & PLT\_01710 & PAU\_02201 & PAK\_02008 \\
\textbf{PVC8} & PAU\_03385 & PAK\_03196 & PAU\_01968 & PAK\_01794 & PLT\_02561 & PAU\_02068 & PAK\_01890 & PLT\_02431 & PAU\_02782 & PLT\_01689 & PAK\_02613 & PLT\_01729 & PLT\_01751 & PLT\_01709 & PAU\_02200 & PAK\_02007 \\
\textbf{PVC9} & PAU\_03384 & PAK\_03195 & PAU\_01969 & PAK\_01795 & PLT\_02560 & PAU\_02067 & PAK\_01889 & PLT\_02432 & PAU\_02783 & PLT\_01688 & PAK\_02614 & PLT\_01728 & PLT\_01750 & PLT\_01708 & PAU\_02199 & PAK\_02006 \\
\textbf{PVC10} & PAU\_03383 & PAK\_03194 & PAU\_01970 & PAK\_01796 & PLT\_02559 & PAU\_02066 & PAK\_01888 & PLT\_02433 & PAU\_02784 & PLT\_01687 & PAK\_02615 & PLT\_01727 & PLT\_01749 & PLT\_01707 & PAU\_02198 & PAK\_02005 \\
\textbf{PVC11} & PAU\_03382 & PAK\_03193 & PAU\_01971 & PAK\_01797 & PLT\_02558 & PAU\_02065 & PAK\_01887 & PLT\_02434 & PAU\_02785 & PLT\_01686 & PAK\_02616 & PLT\_01726 & PLT\_01748 & PLT\_01706 & PAU\_02197 & PAK\_02004 \\
\textbf{PVC12} & PAU\_03381 & PAK\_03192 & PAU\_01972 & PAK\_01798 & PLT\_02557 & PAU\_02064 & PAK\_01886 & PLT\_02435 & PAU\_02786 & PLT\_01685 & PAK\_02617 & PLT\_01725 & PLT\_01747 & PLT\_01705 & PAU\_02196 & PAK\_02002 \\
\textbf{PVC13} & PAU\_03380 & PAK\_03191 & PAU\_01973 & PAK\_01799 & PLT\_02556 &  &  &  & PAU\_02787 & PLT\_01684 & PAK\_02618 & PLT\_01724 & PLT\_01746 & PLT\_01704 & PAU\_02195 & PAK\_02001 \\
\textbf{PVC14} & PAU\_03379 & PAK\_03190 & PAU\_01974 & PAK\_01800 & PLT\_02555 & PAU\_02063 & PAK\_01885 & PLT\_02436 & PAU\_02788 & PLT\_01683 & PAK\_02619 & PLT\_01722 & PLT\_01745 & PLT\_01703 \\
\textbf{PVC15} & PAU\_03378 & PAK\_03189 & PAU\_01975 & PAK\_01801 & PLT\_02554 & PAU\_02062 & PAK\_01884 & PLT\_02437 & PAU\_02789 & PLT\_01682 & PAK\_02620 & PLT\_01721 & PLT\_01744 & PLT\_01702 & PAU\_02191 & PAK\_01997 \\
\textbf{PVC16} & PAU\_03377 & PAK\_03188 & PAU\_01976 & PAK\_01802 & PLT\_02553 & PAU\_02061 & PAK\_01883 & PLT\_02438 & PAU\_02790 & PLT\_01681 & PAK\_02621 & PLT\_01720 & PLT\_01743 & PLT\_01701 & PAU\_02190 & PAK\_01996 \\

\end{tabularx}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

So it currently looks like this. I'm more or less happy with the breadth of the table and where it finishes at the top of the document, but would like to use a fraction more of the space at the bottom (footer side).

[image]
[image]

I've tried a number of solutions (newgeometry, adjustwidth, v/hspace, textheight) but without much success. Changing the textheight seems the most appropriate so that `tabularx` then spans the width, giving a little more space to the rest of the cells, but I don't seem to be able to return the document to its original state fully after the fact and I'd like to keep the footer spacing etc consistent with the rest of the doc, but just reclaim that space slightly.

Comment: Reclaim that space how?  By adding extra rows of data?  By shifting the `tabularx` content downward?  What exactly do you seek?  For example, adding a `\vspace*{2ex}` immediately after the `\begin{landscape}` will shift the whole content.

Comment: No extra data, I just want the tabular to be slightly wider, beginning closer to the bottom rule, which should have the effect of spacing the table content ever so slightly

Comment: Then merely revise your `\arraystretch` to `\def\arraystretch{1.4}`.

Comment: No I think the document being landscape is confusing things here. `arraystretch` will increase the table dimensions towards the right hand edge ( if we consider the page as portrait) right? I want the table to move slightly further toward what would be the bottom edge in portrait view - to occupy more of the area boxed in red in the images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I did was to modifiy the invocation of `tabularx` to include the negative `\hspace` in the 3rd argument as

```
\begin{tabularx}{1.02\linewidth}{ @{\hspace{-12pt}}p{0.04\linewidth} CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC }
```

Here is the MWE.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, 11pt]{report}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage[left=4cm, right=2cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{ltablex} 
    \newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%%%% Configure Fancy Header %%%%%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\headsep 25pt
\headheight 20pt
\setlength{\topmargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\textheight}{670pt}

\fancypagestyle{IHA-fancy-style}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\slshape \leftmark}
  \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage\ }
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}% Line at the header visible
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}% Line at the footer visible
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{IHA-fancy-style}
\lhead{\textsf{Chapter I}}
\rhead{\textsf{Chapter Title}}

\begin{landscape}
\scriptsize
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=off, justification=justified, font=footnotesize}
\rowcolors{1}{gray!10}{white}
\def\arraystretch{1.2}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.01em}
\begin{tabularx}{1.02\linewidth}{ @{\hspace{-12pt}}p{0.04\linewidth} CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC }
\hiderowcolors
\caption[Caption]{Some caption text}
\label{label}\\

\multirow{2}{*}{ORF} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{PNF}  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{CIF} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{LOPT} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{UNIT4} &  \multicolumn{2}{c}{UNIT2} & UNIT1 & UNIT3  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{LUMT} \\ \cmidrule{2-3} \cmidrule{4-6} \cmidrule{7-9} \cmidrule{10-11} \cmidrule{12-13}  \cmidrule{14-14} \cmidrule{15-15} \cmidrule{16-17}
 & 43949 & Kingscliff & 43949 & Kingscliff & TT01 & 43949 & Kingscliff & TT01 & 43949 & TT01 & Kingscliff & TT01 & TT01 & TT01 & 43949 & Kingscliff \\ 
 \hline
 \showrowcolors
\textbf{PVC1} & PAU\_03392 & PAK\_03203 & PAU\_01961 & PAK\_01787 & PLT\_02568 & PAU\_02074 & PAK\_01896 & PLT\_02424 & PAU\_02775 & PLT\_01696 & PAK\_02606 & PLT\_01736 & PLT\_01758 & PLT\_01716 & PAU\_02206 & PAK\_02014 \\ 
\textbf{PVC2} & PAU\_03391 & PAK\_03202 & PAU\_01962 & PAK\_01788 & PLT\_02567 & PAU\_02073 & PAK\_01895 & PLT\_02425 & PAU\_02776 & PLT\_01695 & PAK\_02607 & PLT\_01735 & PLT\_01757 & PLT\_01715 & PAU\_02205 & PAK\_02013 \\
\textbf{PVC3} & PAU\_03390 & PAK\_03201 & PAU\_01963 & PAK\_01789 & PLT\_02566 &  &  & PLT\_02426 & PAU\_02777 & PLT\_01694 & PAK\_02608 & PLT\_01734 & PLT\_01756 & PLT\_01714 &  & PAK\_02012 \\
\textbf{PVC4} & PAU\_03389 & PAK\_03200 & PAU\_01964 & PAK\_01790 & PLT\_02565 & PAU\_02072 & PAK\_01894 & PLT\_02427 & PAU\_02778 & PLT\_01693 & PAK\_02609 & PLT\_01733 & PLT\_01755 & PLT\_01713 & PAU\_02204 & PAK\_02011 \\
\textbf{PVC5} & PAU\_03388 & PAK\_03199 & PAU\_01965 & PAK\_01791 & PLT\_02564 & PAU\_02071 & PAK\_01893 & PLT\_02428 & PAU\_02779 & PLT\_01692 & PAK\_02610 & PLT\_01732 & PLT\_01754 & PLT\_01712 & PAU\_02203 & PAK\_02010 \\
\textbf{PVC6} & PAU\_03387 & PAK\_03198 & PAU\_01966 & PAK\_01792 & PLT\_02563 & PAU\_02070 & PAK\_01892 & PLT\_02429 & PAU\_02780 & PLT\_01691 & PAK\_02611 & PLT\_01731 & PLT\_01753 & PLT\_01711 & PAU\_02202 & PAK\_02009 \\
\textbf{PVC7} & PAU\_03386 & PAK\_03197 & PAU\_01967 & PAK\_01793 & PLT\_02562 & PAU\_02069 & PAK\_01891 & PLT\_02430 & PAU\_02781 & PLT\_01690 & PAK\_02612 & PLT\_01730 & PLT\_01752 & PLT\_01710 & PAU\_02201 & PAK\_02008 \\
\textbf{PVC8} & PAU\_03385 & PAK\_03196 & PAU\_01968 & PAK\_01794 & PLT\_02561 & PAU\_02068 & PAK\_01890 & PLT\_02431 & PAU\_02782 & PLT\_01689 & PAK\_02613 & PLT\_01729 & PLT\_01751 & PLT\_01709 & PAU\_02200 & PAK\_02007 \\
\textbf{PVC9} & PAU\_03384 & PAK\_03195 & PAU\_01969 & PAK\_01795 & PLT\_02560 & PAU\_02067 & PAK\_01889 & PLT\_02432 & PAU\_02783 & PLT\_01688 & PAK\_02614 & PLT\_01728 & PLT\_01750 & PLT\_01708 & PAU\_02199 & PAK\_02006 \\
\textbf{PVC10} & PAU\_03383 & PAK\_03194 & PAU\_01970 & PAK\_01796 & PLT\_02559 & PAU\_02066 & PAK\_01888 & PLT\_02433 & PAU\_02784 & PLT\_01687 & PAK\_02615 & PLT\_01727 & PLT\_01749 & PLT\_01707 & PAU\_02198 & PAK\_02005 \\
\textbf{PVC11} & PAU\_03382 & PAK\_03193 & PAU\_01971 & PAK\_01797 & PLT\_02558 & PAU\_02065 & PAK\_01887 & PLT\_02434 & PAU\_02785 & PLT\_01686 & PAK\_02616 & PLT\_01726 & PLT\_01748 & PLT\_01706 & PAU\_02197 & PAK\_02004 \\
\textbf{PVC12} & PAU\_03381 & PAK\_03192 & PAU\_01972 & PAK\_01798 & PLT\_02557 & PAU\_02064 & PAK\_01886 & PLT\_02435 & PAU\_02786 & PLT\_01685 & PAK\_02617 & PLT\_01725 & PLT\_01747 & PLT\_01705 & PAU\_02196 & PAK\_02002 \\
\textbf{PVC13} & PAU\_03380 & PAK\_03191 & PAU\_01973 & PAK\_01799 & PLT\_02556 &  &  &  & PAU\_02787 & PLT\_01684 & PAK\_02618 & PLT\_01724 & PLT\_01746 & PLT\_01704 & PAU\_02195 & PAK\_02001 \\
\textbf{PVC14} & PAU\_03379 & PAK\_03190 & PAU\_01974 & PAK\_01800 & PLT\_02555 & PAU\_02063 & PAK\_01885 & PLT\_02436 & PAU\_02788 & PLT\_01683 & PAK\_02619 & PLT\_01722 & PLT\_01745 & PLT\_01703 \\
\textbf{PVC15} & PAU\_03378 & PAK\_03189 & PAU\_01975 & PAK\_01801 & PLT\_02554 & PAU\_02062 & PAK\_01884 & PLT\_02437 & PAU\_02789 & PLT\_01682 & PAK\_02620 & PLT\_01721 & PLT\_01744 & PLT\_01702 & PAU\_02191 & PAK\_01997 \\
\textbf{PVC16} & PAU\_03377 & PAK\_03188 & PAU\_01976 & PAK\_01802 & PLT\_02553 & PAU\_02061 & PAK\_01883 & PLT\_02438 & PAU\_02790 & PLT\_01681 & PAK\_02621 & PLT\_01720 & PLT\_01743 & PLT\_01701 & PAU\_02190 & PAK\_01996 \\

\end{tabularx}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect thank you! Love it when there's a nice simple solution.